# Mutate swift array of strings (swift 2)

Tags: arrays, swift, swift2

I have an array of Strings. For example, this:

```
var stringArray1 = ["abcdef", "bcdefg", "cdefgh"]
```

I want to mutate the array and take out the first 3 characters of each string. The result would be this:

```
var newStringArray1 = ["def", "efg", "fgh"]
```

Taking from Apple's Documentation, I tried this:

```
func mutateArray(x: [String]) -> [String] {
    var newArray = [String]()
    for i in x {
        let range =  i.startIndex.advancedBy(3)
        i.removeRange(range)
        newArray.append(i)
    }
    return newArray
}
```

but this line:

```
i.removeRange(range)
```

gave me an error: "Cannot use mutating member on mutable value: "i" is a "let" constant."

how can I change the array like this? I have heard it is possible with the map() function as well, but when searching about the map function, most of the explanations I received were from swift 1/1.2, and it changed in swift 2.

thanks

Comment: and if you set i as var, the program will crash ... i is index in the array, not in the strings inside!

Comment: oh i doesn't represent the contents of the index, but the index itself. that makes sense as to why I got the error then. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the powerful `map` function this way:

```
func mutatedArray(array: [String]) -> [String] {
    return array.map {
        $0.substringFromIndex($0.startIndex.advancedBy(3))
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
var list0 = ["abcdef", "bcdefg", "cdefgh"]
mutatedArray(list0) // ["def", "efg", "fgh"]

var list1 = ["def", "efg", "fgh"]
mutatedArray(list1) // ["", "", ""]
```

### Extension

You can also write the function as an extension available for `Arrays` of `Strings`.

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element == String {
    func mutatedArray(removeChars: Int) -> [String] {
        return self.map {
            $0.substringFromIndex($0.startIndex.advancedBy(removeChars))
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
var list1 = ["def", "efg", "fgh"]
list1.mutatedArray(2) // ["f", "g", "h"]
```

### Note

Please note I changed the name of the function to `mutatedArray` since it is returning a new array and it's not changing the original one.

Comment: lots of cool stuff here I didn't know you could do in swift! thanks.

Comment: is the "extension SequenceType where Generator.Element == String" any different than "Extension String : { // code here }" syntax?

Comment: The difference is that if you write `extension String { ... }` you are adding something to `String`. On the other hand with `extension SequenceType where Generator.Element == String { ... }`you are adding functionalities to the `SequenceType` protocol **when** the element of the sequence is a `String` (e.g. an `Array of String` because `Array` does conform to `SequenceType`). This is part of the beauty of a `Protocol-Oriented` language like Swift :-)

Answer (score 3):

Two solutions:

- using `substringFromIndex`

  ```
  func mutateArray(x: [String]) -> [String] {
    var newArray = [String]()
    for i in x {
      newArray.append(i.substringFromIndex(i.startIndex.advancedBy(3)))
    }
    return newArray
  }


  let stringArray1 = ["abcdef", "bcdefg", "cdefgh"]
  let trimmedStringArray = mutateArray(stringArray1)
  ```
- using `map`

  ```
  let trimmedStringArray = stringArray1.map {$0.substringFromIndex($0.startIndex.advancedBy(3))}
  ```

In both cases you should check for the length of the input string if it's not guaranteed that there are always at least 3 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the "counter" (not really a counter in this case) variable in a `for in` loop. Use a normal loop and create a new object.

```
//standard for
for (var j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
    var i: String = x[i] //copy contents of object
    let range =  i.startIndex.advancedBy(3)
    i.removeRange(range)
    newArray.append(i)
}
```